# how do I perform an md5sum on an exploded ear?

Tags: java, war, ear, md5sum

The majority of application artifacts in my workplace are unexploded ear or war files. Since they're simple files, it's easy to perform an md5sum against the artifacts for comparison. A small subset of the applications are deployed as exploded ears. As directories, I'm unable to perform a simple md5sum against it. I'm looking for an alternative - either a more flexible utility that will perform a hash against artifacts of different file types, or different technique.

One thought I had was to compress the ear or war directory on the fly (either as a temporary file or as a pipe) and to run md5sum against this transient artifact. This would be my preference, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to md5sum their absolute path? It can be an alternative. For a file, you can md5sum its absolute path with its content to avoid conflit with files that have the same content as the directory absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the [MessageDigest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class to create your hash... note that the various `update()` methods on this class simply take `byte` or `byte[]` or `ByteBuffer` and do not rely on where those bytes are coming from.

So what I would at least consider doing - depending on efficiency and how quickly this process would run - would be to iterate through your files and `update()` your MD5 sum with the contents of each file in turn. Continue updating until the end, and top it off with a final `digest()` to get the end result.

You will have to be *absolutely* certain that you iterate through the files in the same order every time, since obviously a different order will result in a different hash.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to compress the directory to a pipe and then to perform and md5sum on the pipe:

```
jar -c <directory> | md5sum
```

Comment: A problem with the above is that it returns a different result each time!